# How can I detect when android keyboard appears/disappears? (5.02)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I updated my phone and the code I had which worked before does not work in 5.02 (new version I just updated phone to). Is there a way that will work with all versions? Here is my code that does not work anymore (it says it is visible when it is not):

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();

                if (heightDiff > 100)
                {
                    System.out.println("test:    keyboard visible");

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)bottomSelectionLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = 0;
                    bottomSelectionLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)bottomSeperatorLine.getLayoutParams();
                    lp2.height = 0;
                    bottomSeperatorLine.setLayoutParams(lp2);

                    bottomSelectionLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bottomSeperatorLine.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("test:    keyboard invisible");

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)bottomSelectionLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = (int) bottomSelectionLayoutStartingHeight;
                    bottomSelectionLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)bottomSeperatorLine.getLayoutParams();
                    lp2.height = (int)bottomSeperatorLineStartingHeight;
                    bottomSeperatorLine.setLayoutParams(lp2);

                    bottomSelectionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomSeperatorLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following line to your layout XML? This will help support `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` that you have added to your AndroidManifest.xml in versions 21 and greater

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: The problem is that the keyboard is not getting detected properly. It is being detected as visible when it is not up. Regardless I tried adding your code to my manifest and it does not fix the problem :(

Comment: Ok here is a bit more information that might help. When the keyboard is visible, heightDiff is 146. When the keyboard is NOT visible, heightDiff is 670.